# Is there a good strategy to make a function a productive function?

Tags: haskell

*<sub>**EDIT:** It seems what I was calling "lazy" here, isn't what "lazy" means. I am not sure what the proper term is. Some people are saying that the term I am looking for is "productive", but I can't find any definitions of that term in this context. What I want is a function that can work with infinite lists. I will change any "lazy" into "productive", using my best understanding of the term.</sub>*

The function

```
f a = a:(f (a-1))
```

generates an infinite list, in a productive way. Because of the `a:` being in front of every other evaluation.

This means you can do `take 10 (f 0)` and it's fine.

However, the function

```
h a = h (a ++ (map (-1) a))
```

isn't productive, and will never terminate. Since the `a ++` is inside of another evaluation.
Because of this, you cannot do `head (h [0])`, even though it is clear that it is 0.

Is there a general strategy I can apply to turn a non-productive function into a productive function?

Specifically, the problem I'm trying to solve is to make the following  productive while lazily consuming its second argument:

```
binarily a [] = a
binarily a (b:bs) = binarily (a ++ map (b+) a) bs
```

Comment: Your `h` is lazy, but it isn't terminating.  There's no condition to tell the compiler when to stop apply `h`.

Comment: cf. http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17481/does-productive-function-mean-just-that-in-me-oneill-the-genuine-sieve-of-er

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`h` generates a growing sequence. On `[0]` for example:

```
[0] ++
[0, -1] ++
[0, -1, -1, -2] ++
[0, -1, -1, -2, -1, -2, -2, -3] ++ ...
```

Note that it shows the pattern `[x, f x, f (f x), …]`—at each step, you’re computing one more iteration of the function. That’s exactly what `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]` is for, and the fold of `++`s is exactly `concat`:

```
h = concat . iterate go
  where go x = x ++ map (subtract 1) x
```

Here’s one implementation of `binarily` using the same principle:

```
binarily a bs
  = concatMap fst
  . takeWhile (not . null . snd)
  $ iterate go (a, bs)
  where
  go (acc, b : bs) = (acc ++ map (b +) acc, bs)
  go x = x
```

We `iterate` the function and `take` elements from the stream `While` `bs` (`snd`) is `not . null`—if it’s infinite, then this just takes the whole stream—and then we `concat` the intermediate accumulators (`map fst`).

You’ll notice that if you didn’t have the `takeWhile` in there, you would end up with an infinitely repeating series of tuples where the `snd` is `[]`. So what we’re doing is streaming until we hit a fixed point, i.e., turning recursion (`fix`) into streaming. :)

Comment: Your answer is very good, and does answer the main question. However you binarily function isn't completely right, but I can try and think through it and get it right. Thank you!

Comment: @user1433771: Thanks, I realised that I missed the last iteration but haven’t taken the time to go back and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The 'general strategy' is to define your function so that it can compute a part of the result value before recursing.

In `f`, the topmost expression is an application of the `(:)` function, which is non-strict in its second argument. This means that it doesn't even need to evaluate `f (a-1)`. if you don't need the remainder of the list.

In `h`, the first thing the function does is to recurse - i.e. it doesn't produce a "partial result".

Your `binarily` function actually is "lazy": it's non-strict in its first argument, so

```
take 10 $ binarily [1..] [1..5]
```

terminates.

Comment: Yes, it is non strict over the first argument, but not over the second one. I'll edit the OP so that this is more clear

Answer (score 2):

The proper term that you were looking for is *productive*, not just "lazy"...

`head (h [10])` is just not defined, at all. The reduction sequence is: `h [10] => h [10,9] => h [10,9,9,8] => h [10,9,9,8,9,8,8,7] => ...`. It's true that the head of this internal sequence is always the same, `10`, but the reduction itself never stops. And no, it's not the same as `f 10 => [10,9,8,7,...`.

Your function,

```
binarily a [] = a
binarily a (b:bs) = binarily (a ++ map (b+) a) bs
{-  try it out with [b1,b2,b3,b4] :
a                          b1     the arguments received;
a1@(a  ++ (map (b1+) a))   b2     if we've already produced a, we just need 
                                       to produce  (map (b1+) a)  next
a2@(a1 ++ (map (b2+) a1))  b3     if we've already produced a1, we just need 
                                       to produce  (map (b2+) a1)  next
a3@(a2 ++ (map (b3+) a2))  b4     ai@... name the interim values
a4@(a3 ++ (map (b4+) a3))  []     a4 is returned  -}
```

is equivalent to

```
import Data.List (mapAccumL)

-- mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])

binarily a bs = (last . snd) (mapAccumL g a bs)
 where
   g a b = let anew = a ++ map (b+) a
           in (anew, anew)             -- (next_accum, part_result)
```

`mapAccumL` captures the pattern of accumulating and producing parts of the full result at the same time. The list `:: [y]` (the `snd` field of its return value) is produced lazily, built from all `y`s as they are returned by the step function which is called for each `x` in the list `:: [x]` (your `(b:bs)`). So as long as we're ignoring the final accumulated value in the `fst` field of the result, the function works with infinite input too.

Obviously part of the next result is present in the previous one here, and can be returned right away:

```
binarily a bs = a ++ (concat . snd) (mapAccumL g a bs)
 where
   g a b = let                     -- for each b in bs:
               res = map (b+) a    --    this part of the result
               anew = a ++ res     --    next accumulator value
           in (anew, res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another, perhaps more "concrete" way of writing your lazy/productive `binarily`:

```
binarily a l = a ++ binRest a l

binRest a [] = []
binRest a (b:bs) = a' ++ binRest (a ++ a') bs
  where
    a' = map (b+) a
```

EDIT: I was asked for some explanation of my thought process. Let's start by looking at what the `binarily` in the original post passes as its first argument at each step, if we start with `binarily a (b1:b2:b3:...)`:

```
a
a ++ map (b1+) a
a ++ map (b1+) a ++ map (b2+) (a ++ map (b1+) a)
a ++ map (b1+) a ++ map (b2+) (a ++ map (b1+) a) ++ map (b3+) (a ++ map (b1+) a ++ map (b2+) (a ++ map (b1+) a))
```

It is clear that we can produce the `a ++` pretty immediately, and then in the next step `map (b1+)` is applied to that, so a straight `concat $ iterate ... a` like in @JonPurdy's answer first seems like it should work. Actually, because we go through the `bs` list, the `scanl` function is a better match than `iterate`.

But if we try that, we see there is still a mismatch: the part added in the third step above is not a function of the part *added* to the argument in the second step, but of the *whole* argument in the second step. `concat $ scanl ...` doesn't quite fit this.

It turns out, in fact, that the produced part in the very *first* step doesn't fit the regular pattern of all the rest.

Thus I split into two functions: First, `binarily`, which handles what to produce in the first step, and then passes on to `binRest` for all the other steps.

Secondly, `binRest`, which takes as its first argument everything produced so far, and uses it to calculate what to produce in this step, and then recurses.

Comment: Your code does generete the desired output, but I'm still not too sure what thought process you went through to get to this solution.

Comment: scanl is a bad fit, because it just accumulates; mapAccumL is a natural fit because it both accumulates and produces parts of the result, like your explicit recursion version does as well.

Comment: @WillNess Right, though it still requires treating the first step specially.

Comment: yes, the beginning is not a step. (I didn't even have to think about it, using mapAccumL just forced me to write it this way :) ).