# How to optimize filtering of a list

Tags: haskell

To learn Haskell I've been solving programming challenges. While trying to solve one problem found in Hackerrank about filtering elements of a list of thousand of elements, I've been unable to pass the time tests.

**The problem statement is**: from a list of elements filter those that appear more than **k** times and print them in their order of appearance.

The best I've come so far is this code:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.List (intercalate, elemIndices, foldl')
import qualified Data.Set as S

-- Improved version of nub
nub' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
nub' = go S.empty
  where go _ [] = []
        go s (x:xs) | S.member x s = go s xs
                    | otherwise    = x : go (S.insert x s) xs

-- Extract Int from ByteString     
getIntFromBS :: BSC.ByteString -> Int
getIntFromBS = fst . fromJust . BSC.readInt

{- 
    Parse read file:

    a k1
    n1 n2 n3 n4 ... 
    c k2
    m1 m2 m3 m4 ...

    into appropriate format:

    [(k1, [n1,n2,n3,n4]), (k2, [m1,m2,m3,m4])]
-}
createGroups :: [BSC.ByteString] -> [(Int, [Int])]
createGroups [] = []
createGroups (p:v:xs) =
    let val = getIntFromBS $ last $ BSC.split ' ' p
        grp = foldr (\x acc -> getIntFromBS x : acc) [] $ BSC.split ' ' v
    in (val, grp) : createGroups xs

solve :: (Int, [Int]) -> String
solve (k, v) = intercalate " " $ if null res then ["-1"] else res
    where
        go n acc =
            if length (elemIndices n v) > k
                then show n : acc
                else          acc
        res = foldr go [] (nub' v)

fullSolve :: [BSC.ByteString] -> [String]
fullSolve xs = foldl' (\acc tupla -> acc ++ [solve tupla]) [] $ createGroups xs

main = do
    BSC.getContents >>= mapM_ putStrLn . fullSolve . drop 1 . BSC.lines
```

I would like to know where can I improve this code. I've tried many variants using maps,vectors, parsing and not parsing the read strings from the file to `Int`, but the shown code is the best I have.

Comment: The `acc ++ [solve tupla]` part worries me, that is going to have terrible runtime performance.  Consider using a `Data.Seq` here instead

Comment: Could you explain why that specific part worries you? How did you notice it?

Comment: Concatenating a single element to the end of a singly linked list (what Haskell lists are) is a O(n) operation.  You have to traverse the entire list every time you append an element.  Prepending (or consing) an element is O(1).  These sorts of details stand out when reading Haskell code, the `++ [single element]` becomes quite noticeable with experience.

Comment: I also took the liberty of reformatting your code (I hope I didn't break anything, shouldn't have...) to get rid of the really long lines.  It just looks better on SO and in an editor.  Breaking these lines up really helps to spot errors and potential bottlenecks

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that, tried with a foldr since it works well with operators that are lazy on their second argument but that would give me the list reversed, then I whould have to reverse it again. Since I am using foldl strict thought that would solve the problem.

Comment: Using `foldl'` will make the operation strict, but that doesn't make the operation cheaper.  Use `Data.Sequence` for this fold (or just `reverse` and use `foldr`) so you can use its O(1) operation for appending an element.  I can just about guarantee you that this is your problem.

Comment: `foldl' (\acc tupla -> acc ++ [solve tupla]) [] $ createGroups xs` is just `map solve $ createGroups xs` (evaluated with quadratic amounts of unnecessary list traversal). Concatenating a single element to the end of a list is a code smell, because it's a quadratic way of growing a list if you do it repeatedly. It would be quicker better to prepend then reverse, because that's linear, but you'd be fastest with lazy production (as map does) like `first element : recursive call to make rest of elements`.

Comment: As @AndrewC says, you're using a fold where you could be using a map.  There's actually several places you have `foldr (\x acc -> f x : acc) []`, which can all be replaced with a simple `map f`, such as in `createGroups` and `solve`.  You could probably get away without using any explict `fold`s in this code.

Comment: Tried following the aforementioned recommendations (remove unnecessary folds in createGroups and in fullSolve, not sure if the foldr inside solve can be removed) but it is still inefficient.

Comment: The `solve` function is a bottleneck, particularly if the list of numbers is large. `nub'` is better than the original `nub`, but you throw that away by processing the list multiple times for each distinct Int. You'd be better off incrementing a value in a `Data.Map.Strict`, a realisation Chris Drost came to before me. (You can use a fold for that, with the Map as the accumulator.) That way you traverse the list once and don't need to calculate the nub first. You can then filter the Map for values above k, then convert it to a list and `map show` it. `unwords` is briefer than `intercalate " "`

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work. I mean map with fold, not with the State monad. Also there is a problem with that approach, the order of appearance isn't preserved.

Comment: To preserve order, you could do the nub' thing and look up each in turn from the Map.Map that you build up.

Comment: @AndrewC I already solved it by simply saving the position with zip. I'll post my solution

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion this could have been done, very efficiently, using only _right folds_. see http://pastebin.com/4rNJwCGU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though at the beginning I had tried with Data.Map, it lacked the optimizations pointed out in the comments regarding the use of folds vs. maps, and was also missing the desired order of output (by order of appearance). The final solution is as follows:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}
import Control.Monad (liftM, replicateM_)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.List (foldl', sort, unwords)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC

getIntFromBS :: BSC.ByteString -> Int
getIntFromBS = fst.fromJust.BSC.readInt

solve :: Int -> [Int] -> String
solve k = unwords . map snd . sort . map finalPair . filter hasHighFreq . M.toList . foldl' insMap M.empty . zip [0..]
    where
        f _ _ (i, old_value) = (i, old_value + 1)
        insMap m' (i, x) = M.insertWithKey f x (i,1) m'
        hasHighFreq (_, (_, freq)) = freq >= k
        finalPair (val, (i, freq)) = (i, show val)

main = do
    n <- liftM getIntFromBS BSC.getLine
    replicateM_ n $ do
        [_, k] <- liftM (map getIntFromBS . BSC.words) BSC.getLine
        vals   <- liftM (map getIntFromBS . BSC.words) BSC.getLine
        let res = solve k vals
        putStrLn (if null res then "-1" else res)
```

Comment: "folds vs maps" is not a problem; the problem was the function which was used in the fold. . Folds are good, they let you fuse `map`, `filter` and `toList` into one fold:

   ``... M.foldlWithKey' (\a n (i,c)-> if c>k then (i,n):a else a) [] ...``. Also, [Data.IntMap.Strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-IntMap-Strict.html) says *"benchmarks show that [IntMap] is ... (much) faster on insertions and deletions when compared to a generic size-balanced map implementation"*.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to solve that problem I would probably first try using a `Data.Map.Strict` (for O(log *n*) modifications) hidden in the operations with a `Control.Monad.State.Strict` monad transformer.

```
import Data.Map.Strict
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

type SIO x = StateT (Map String Int) IO x

incCount :: String -> Int -> Int -> Int
incCount _ _ old_val = 1 + old_val

incAndGetCount :: String -> SIO Int
incAndGetCount s = fmap unMaybe $ state $ insertLookupWithKey incCount s 1
    where unMaybe (Just x) = x + 1
          unMaybe Nothing = 1

processKey :: String -> SIO ()
processKey s = do
    ct <- incAndGetCount s
    if ct == 5 then lift (putStrLn s) else return ()

process :: [String] -> IO ()
process list = evalStateT (mapM_ processKey list) empty
```

While I feel this code is more elegant I have no way of knowing whether it is faster without actually seeing the test data. In any case this amounts to an imperative loop which puts the string in a dictionary retrieving the number of times it's been seen so far, and then if that number is 5 it prints that string to the standard output.

You'll need to combine it with an appropriate `main` method, of course.

Comment: I am unable to compile your code. I've been trying to fix it but I still don't understand Monad Transformers well enough to be able to fix.

Comment: The problem is with `process` function. The declaration should be `process :: [String] -> IO (Map String Int)`

Comment: Sorry @OneEyeQuestion, I rattled off a bunch of code based on types but I accidentally wrote `execStateT` (which gives an `IO (Map ...)`) rather than `evalStateT` (which gives an `IO ()`), but I declared the signature explicitly the other way. I've fixed the code above.

Comment: Was confused by execStateT, but now I understand since I am familiar with evalState. Thank you. Going to test your solution. I had tried before with maps but with a more rudimentary solution using folds.

Comment: I've been trying to adapt your code @ChrisDrost to suit my needs, namely that it follows the output format generated by doing unwords (n1 n2 n3...) but with no success. Could you help me / point me out how to achieve this? Tried changing the IO Monad for a List to store on each state the final items.

Answer (score 0):

*edit: oops, this is wrong. The order produced is "as discovered", but should be "as first seen in the original list". This can be tweaked with the indexing and the sorting... Unfortunately this means it ceases to be productive then.*

You can make this function more productive, obviating any need for indexing and sorting too, with

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import Data.List 

-- mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])

solve :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
solve k ns = concat . snd $ mapAccumL g M.empty ns
  where
    g m n = case u of         -- for each n in ns, with updating m,
              Nothing -> (M.insert n 1 m, [n | k==1])
              Just c -> (m2, [n | c==k-1])
     where
        (u,m2) = M.updateLookupWithKey (\n c-> Just (c+1)) n m
```

As soon as *k*th instance of an element is encountered in the input list, we can produce it. The final frequencies map is ignored.

It's better to make your functions more focused. Having produced the list of `Int`s, you can pass it through `unwords . map show` or what have you.

[Data.IntMap.Strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-IntMap-Strict.html) says *"... benchmarks show that [IntMap] is ... (much) faster on insertions and deletions when compared to a generic size-balanced map implementation"*.

Comment: I also explain `mapAccumL` some more in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26635144/849891).